# SWI-prolog same generation

Tags: prolog, family-tree

I have some facts and rules that I'm trying to use that when I pass a query it says if the two variables are of the same generation (either siblings or cousins).

```
%mother/father DB
mother(lisa, abe).
mother(lisa, sarah).
mother(nancy, john).
mother(mary, jill).
mother(sarah, susan).
mother(susan, jack).
mother(susan, phil).

father(tony, abe).
father(tony, sarah).
father(abe, john).
father(john, jill).
father(bill, susan).
father(rob, jack).
father(rob, phil).
father(jack, jim).

%Parent rule
parent(X,Y):-mother(X,Y).%Defines the parent rule
parent(X,Y):-father(X,Y).

%sibling rule true if X,Y share same parent
sibling(X,Y):-father(Z,X),father(Z,Y),
mother(M,X),mother(M,Y).

cousin(X,Y):-parent(P,X),parent(Q,Y),sibling(P,Q).

%returns true if X is an ancestor of Y
ancestor(X,Y):-parent(X,Y);parent(X,Z),ancestor(Z,Y).


same_generation(X,Y):-ancestor(Z,X),ancestor(A,Y),sibling(Z,A).
```

Unfortunately the problem I'm getting is that when I test the query for a child and parent ex.same_generation(Jack,Susan), I get true (that is incorrect)!

Any help would be great!

Here is the family tree:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Ifx.png)

Comment: You need to model the number of generations, too.  And use `jack` in place of `Jack`

Comment: So, I'm trying to get a rule that returns a number N that tells how many generations apart two people are. I'm not sure where to start, sorry.

Comment: @false,now I can get a query going for cousins but the same query returns true when I pass two siblings. Suggestions?

Comment: You can add a parameter to ancestor, something like howManyGenerations.  Then in same_generation, ensure they're the same value.